# Are roundish cracks on a cricket bat a serious issue?

Tags: cricket, equipment

I brought a new cricket bat and took it to nets for knocking in, but the bat acquired a number of roundish cracks as shown in the picture. Is this a serious issue I should I worry about it or it is usual?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're serious about keeping up cricket as a hobby, it might serve you well to think about oiling it with a thin rag to make sure cracks like this don't appear. Cracks like this won't cause any significant impacts but to avoid larger ones, oil it up. After oiling it, leave it for about 12 hours then gently tap it with a mallet to smooth out any raised areas.